# Xcode Error, after I close the simulator I see this error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, runtime-error, xcode12

CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (B0CA6F06-B4A2-4485-AF6F-57EF0B5BABD5) - Runtime: iOS 14.3 (18C61) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
(lldb)

Never seen this before, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you closed the simulator before stoping the app.

[image]

Stop the app running before closing the simulator by clicking the stop button or

or using the command shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>